# Mobile Safari Tap Highlight effect

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uibutton, core-animation, uitouch

In mobile Safari when you tap on the lower navigation bar to add a bookmark, call up the bookmark list, or select a page there is a blurry highlight that appears when you tap the button.

1) What is that little highlight called? (is it the webkit-tap-highlight?)Is there a generic term for this type of effect (I was trying to search for this type of effect and couldn't think of what you would call it)?

2) I'd like to recreate this effect in a regular UIView in my app. So that when the user taps the view a fuzzy dot appears then fades away. I've been able to create a similar effect using the following code (it makes a solid gray dot).

```
// Draw a gray circle where the touch occurred
UIView *touchView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[touchView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
touchView.frame = CGRectMake(point.x-10, point.y-10, 15, 15);
touchView.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
[self addSubview:touchView];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[touchView setAlpha:0.0];
[UIView commitAnimations];
[touchView release];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `UIButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted`.